# i have problem with firewall this question like this:

Tags: debian, firewall

1. configure packet filtering firewall to allow DNS, HTTPS from outside to server
2. configure PAT for HTTP using port 8080 from outside to server
3. deny all other services

and i have problem like this
give ip address client but dont enter the gateway
what should i do??
 i have 1 server,router and debian client

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking (aside from general guidance, which is outside the scope of this forum).

Answer (score 2):

Both are done by way of the `iptables` command.

First, disable incoming access by default. Note: DO NOT type this in on the command line if you're connected over `ssh` or some such, because you'll lock yourself out.

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

Next, allow already-established connections:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Finally, open the ports you want to allow access to; e.g., for HTTP:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

repeat for other ports.

To get port translation, you need to use the `nat` table:

```
iptables -t nat -A prerouting -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```